# How to matching data from other sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

For example:

Spreadsheet A:

```
John   |  550
Mary   |  430
```

Spreadsheet B:

```
John   | x
Peter  | y
```

And then A get data from B, get the data by the some name to look for and other row:

```
John   | 550 | x
```

Comment: It looks like you need to use vlookup: Check the documentation here https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en

Comment: vlookup seems cannot do the entire column

Comment: You have to specify the range which vlookup is searching. A1 is the top left of your example above, and bottom right would be B2 so your range would be A1:B2. If you had 100 records set up the same way it would be A1:B100

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if the data is in different *spreadsheets* you will need `importrange` to bring it to the same spreadsheet (probably a separate sheet of it, so it doesn't get in the way).

Then, use `vlookup` with `arrayformula`, for example

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(filter(A1:A, len(A1:A)), Sheet2!A:B, 2, False))
```

This says: for each nonempty cell in column A of the current sheet, look up its value in column A of Sheet2, and bring back the corresponding value in column B of Sheet2.